# How to extract a list of columns name based on the means of their data?

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and hope i'll make myself clear enough.

I have a table of several columns which are factors. I want to make a score for each of these columns. Then I want to calculate the mean of each score, and display the list of columns ranked by their mean scores, is that possible ?

Table would be:
`head(musico[,69:73])`

AVIS1 AVIS2 AVIS3 AVIS4 AVIS5
1     2     1     2     3     2
2     2     5     2     3     2
3     3     2     5     5     1
4     1     2     5     5     5
5     1     5     1     3     1
6     4     1     4     5     4

I want to make a score for each:

```
musico$score1<-0  
musico$score1[musico$AVIS1==1]<-1  
musico$score1[musico$AVIS1==2]<-0.5
```

then do the mean of each column score: mean of score1, mean of score2, ...:
`mean(musico$score1), mean(musico$score2), ...`

My goal is to have a list of titles (avis1, avis2,...) ranked by their mean score.

Any advice appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using base although it is somewhat unclear what you want. What does `score1` have to do with `AVIS1`? I think you may be missing some of the data from `musico`.

Based on the example provided, here's a base R solution. `vapply` loops through the data.frame and produces the mean for each column. Then the `stack` and `order` are only there to make the output a dataframe that looks nice.

```r
music <- read.table(text = "
AVIS1 AVIS2 AVIS3 AVIS4 AVIS5
1 2 1 2 3 2
2 2 5 2 3 2
3 3 2 5 5 1
4 1 2 5 5 5
5 1 5 1 3 1
6 4 1 4 5 4", header = TRUE)

means <- vapply(music, mean, 1)
stack(means[order(means, decreasing = TRUE)])

    values   ind
4 4.000000 AVIS4
3 3.166667 AVIS3
2 2.666667 AVIS2
5 2.500000 AVIS5
1 2.166667 AVIS1
```

Comment: Many thanks, the stack instruction was what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it by first introducing a `scores` vector to be used as a lookup. I assume that scores are decreasing by 0.5 and that the number of scores needed are according to the maximum number of levels found in your columns (i.e. 6  seen in `AVIS1`).

Then using `tidyr` you can organise your data set such that you have to variables (i.e. `AVIS` and `Value`) containing the respective levels. Then add a score variable with the `mutate` function from `dplyr` in which the position of the score in the `score` vector matches the value in the `Value` variable. From here you can find the mean scores corresponding to the `AVIS` levels, arrange them accordingly and put them in a list.

```
music <- read.table(text = "
    AVIS1 AVIS2 AVIS3 AVIS4 AVIS5
    1 2 1 2 3 2
    2 2 5 2 3 2
    3 3 2 5 5 1
    4 1 2 5 5 5
    5 1 5 1 3 1
    6 4 1 4 5 4", header = TRUE)              # your data

scores <- seq(1, by = -0.5, length.out = 6)   # vector of scores

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

music2 <- music %>%
  gather(AVIS, Value) %>%                     # here you tidy the data
  mutate(score = scores[Value]) %>%           # match score to value
  group_by(AVIS) %>%                          # group AVIS levels
  summarise(score.mean = mean(score)) %>%     # find mean scores for AVIS levels
  arrange(desc(score.mean))                  

list <- list(AVIS = music2$AVIS)              # here is the list

> list$AVIS
[1] "AVIS1" "AVIS5" "AVIS2" "AVIS3" "AVIS4"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know of the _gather_instruction, very helpful. I end up using the solution proposed by Cole because it seems easier to me.

Comment: Sure. Yeah no problem. Perhaps you should run only `music2 <- music %>% gather(AVIS, Value)` to see how `gather()` manipulates the data set. It's a very neat function.